# How to get Razor intellisense in Visual Studio for client MVVM languages?

Tags: visual-studio, mvvm, data-binding, knockout.js, intellisense

I'm using a javascript library for MVVM style binding. (It's [knockout](https://knockoutjs.com/) enhanced with [KO Punches](https://mbest.github.io/knockout.punches/), but I think this would apply to any such library.)

A typical bit of markup looks like this:

```
<table data-bind="visible: data.topPlayers.length > 0">
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: data.topPlayers">
        <tr class="bold">
            <td>{{user_id}}</td>
            <td>{{displayName}}</td>
            <td class="stickers">{{sticker_Count.toLocaleString()}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The `{{binding}}` syntax causes the library to replace the value in the braces with that property on the model object.

My problem is that Visual Studio doesn't know anything about this, and so I don't get any Intellisense or design time type checking. In particular, if I change something on the view model, for instance, I clean up `user_id` to `userId`, I wouldn't get any help from the compiler to catch this.

This makes refactoring dangerous.

Is there any way to tell Visual Studio about the syntax of my markup and model objects, so that it could provide this kind of assistance in the editor?

Comment: What is your project type and what is your VS  version?

Comment: I'm using "Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019, Version 16.6.2", which is quite up to date. It's a .NET 4.7 MVC web project.

Answer (score 1):

> How to get Razor intellisense in Visual Studio for client MVVM
>   languages?

**I am afraid you cannot get what you want in Visual Studio.**

The default JS intellisense cannot get the intellisense of Embedded binding JS format. The intellisense cannot recognize it due to some reasons.

**However**, in VS Code with the extension [Angular Language Service](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Angular.ng-template), you can get that intellisense by it. And based on it, you could open such web page in vs code and modify it for the moment.

=========================

**PS**: [Resharper extension](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI_oO6lvOK6gIVlDUrCh1PQA6bEAAYASAAEgI16PD_BwE)(VS extension) might have this feature but it's a paid extension, and new users have a 30-day free period of use.

If Resharper does not have this function, I suggest you could suggest a feature to [our User Voice forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html).

[image]

**After that**, you could share the link with us here and anyone who is interested including us will vote it so that it will get more Microsoft's attention.

Comment: I can't really use VS Code, because this is a massive project that I share with others and we rely on numerous extensions and other Visual Studio environmental things. I'm also not using angular itself, so I'm not sure this would help. Would there be any way to do this if instead of using vbhtml or cshtml view files, I could make a dedicated file type, and create a language service for it?